# When using Solrj with Basic auth, giving me error "Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset"

Tags: java, spring, solr, solrj, solrcloud

When using Solrj with Basic auth, giving me error "Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset" (connecting to test host) while if I connect to local Solr (without basic auth) or direct curl, it works without issue. 
Looking for any suggestions/pointers.

Working with curl (connecting to test host):

```
    curl -i --user userName:pwd https://hostname:3001/solr/Subscriptions/select?q=*:*
```

Not working : (connecting to test host)

/*Basic Auth*/

```
    SolrClient client = new 
    HttpSolrClient.Builder("https://hostname:3001/solr/Subscriptions").build();
    QueryRequest req = new QueryRequest(new SolrQuery("*:*"));
    req.setBasicAuthCredentials("userName", "pwd");
    QueryResponse rsp = req.process(client);
```

Working (without basic auth connected to localhost) :

```
    SolrClient client = new 
    HttpSolrClient.Builder("https://localhost:8993/solr/Subscriptions").build();
    SolrQuery query = new SolrQuery();
    query.setQuery("*:*");
    query.setFields("Subscriptions-type","id", "subscriber-id");
    QueryResponse response = client.query(query);
    logger.info("Starting Solr Search to get the complete Subscriptions");
    SolrDocumentList results = response.getResults();
    logger.info("Completed Solr Search to get the complete Subscriptions");
```

a)Not sure why I am getting a "java.net.SocketException: Connection reset" ?
b)Also I have seen that in the reference they are using "req.process(client)" but what is the type of the object "client" ?

Failure Stack trace :-

```
Regular task started using Cron at 12/04/2019 16:04:29
2019-12-04 16:04:31.094  INFO 47033 --- [   scheduling-1] o.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec   : I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request to {s}->https://hostname:3001: Connection reset
2019-12-04 16:04:31.094  INFO 47033 --- [   scheduling-1] o.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec   : Retrying request to {s}->https://hostname:3001
2019-12-04 16:04:31.766  INFO 47033 --- [   scheduling-1] o.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec   : I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request to {s}->https://hostname:3001: Connection reset
2019-12-04 16:04:31.766  INFO 47033 --- [   scheduling-1] o.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec   : Retrying request to {s}->https://hostname:3001
2019-12-04 16:04:32.408  INFO 47033 --- [   scheduling-1] o.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec   : I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request to {s}->https://hostname:3001: Connection reset
2019-12-04 16:04:32.408  INFO 47033 --- [   scheduling-1] o.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec   : Retrying request to {s}->https://hostname:3001
2019-12-04 16:04:33.090 ERROR 47033 --- [   scheduling-1] o.s.s.s.TaskUtils$LoggingErrorHandler    : Unexpected error occurred in scheduled task.

org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServerException: IOException occured when talking to server at: https://hostname:3001/solr/Subscriptions
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient.executeMethod(HttpSolrClient.java:657) ~[solr-solrj-7.4.0.jar:7.4.0 9060ac689c270b02143f375de0348b7f626adebc - jpountz - 2018-06-18 16:55:14]
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient.request(HttpSolrClient.java:255) ~[solr-solrj-7.4.0.jar:7.4.0 9060ac689c270b02143f375de0348b7f626adebc - jpountz - 2018-06-18 16:55:14]
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient.request(HttpSolrClient.java:244) ~[solr-solrj-7.4.0.jar:7.4.0 9060ac689c270b02143f375de0348b7f626adebc - jpountz - 2018-06-18 16:55:14]
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrRequest.process(SolrRequest.java:194) ~[solr-solrj-7.4.0.jar:7.4.0 9060ac689c270b02143f375de0348b7f626adebc - jpountz - 2018-06-18 16:55:14]
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrRequest.process(SolrRequest.java:211) ~[solr-solrj-7.4.0.jar:7.4.0 9060ac689c270b02143f375de0348b7f626adebc - jpountz - 2018-06-18 16:55:14]
    ......
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_45]
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:209) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:465) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:503) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:961) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1363) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1391) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1375) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.createLayeredSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:396) ~[httpclient-4.5.6.jar:4.5.6]
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:355) ~[httpclient-4.5.6.jar:4.5.6]
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:142) ~[httpclient-4.5.6.jar:4.5.6]
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:373) ~[httpclient-4.5.6.jar:4.5.6]
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:394) ~[httpclient-4.5.6.jar:4.5.6]
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:237) ~[httpclient-4.5.6.jar:4.5.6]
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:185) ~[httpclient-4.5.6.jar:4.5.6]
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89) ~[httpclient-4.5.6.jar:4.5.6]
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110) ~[httpclient-4.5.6.jar:4.5.6]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185) ~[httpclient-4.5.6.jar:4.5.6]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83) ~[httpclient-4.5.6.jar:4.5.6]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:56) ~[httpclient-4.5.6.jar:4.5.6]
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient.executeMethod(HttpSolrClient.java:542) ~[solr-solrj-7.4.0.jar:7.4.0 9060ac689c270b02143f375de0348b7f626adebc - jpountz - 2018-06-18 16:55:14]
    ... 20 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Instead of `hostname`, provide the ip address of the machine where solr is running.

Comment: @Sambit, after changing to IP I am now seeing SSL error :-  Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake
 at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:980) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
 at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1363) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
 at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1391) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
 at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1375) ~[n..
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: SSL peer shut down incorrectly

Comment: This is fine. Do you have certificate because your URI says `https`

Answer (score 0):

You have to access the solr server using solrj client library in the following manner. You have to provide the actual IP address of the system running solr and the port number.

```
String solrServerUrl = "https://<IP Address>:<portNo>/solr/Subscriptions";//enter actual IP address and port
SolrClient client = new HttpSolrClient.Builder(solrServerUrl ).build();
```

If the solr server is https enabled, you have to refer to the following reference links.

https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_6/enabling-ssl.html